# Use pandas to condense a dataframe using values from one dataframe to populate a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, transform

I'm trying to use Python pandas to take multiple rows that have `defect_*_day_flag` values as TRUE and FALSE and create a new dataframe that is condensed.  Using the phase_date from the first TRUE occurrence to create a new `*_dttm` column for each of the respective `defect_*_day_flag` columns.

The original data represents a daily snapshot (phase_date) for the state of a given `bug_id`. 
 The data appears similar to the following:

```
phase_date  bug_id  creation_dttm   severity    status  defect_regression_day_flag  defect_reopen_day_flag  defect_backlog_day_flag defect_resolution_day_flag  defect_rejected_day_flag    defect_verified_day_flag    defect_failedtest_day_flag
2019-01-09  113998  2004-01-21 3:15:24  medium  NEW        FALSE    FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
2019-01-10  113998  2004-01-21 3:15:24  medium  NEW        FALSE    FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
2019-01-11  113998  2004-01-21 3:15:24  medium  ASSIGNED    FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
2019-01-12  113998  2004-01-21 3:15:24  medium  IN PROGRESS FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
2019-01-13  113998  2004-01-21 3:15:24  medium  IN PROGRESS FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
2019-01-14  113998  2004-01-21 3:15:24  medium  VERIFIED    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
2019-01-15  113998  2004-01-21 3:15:24  medium  CLOSED  FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
```

And I'm trying to get to:

```
bug_id  creation_dttm   severity    status  regression_dttm reopen_dttm backlog_dttm    resolution_dttm rejected_dttm   verified_dttm   failed_test_dttm
113998  2004-01-21 3:15:24  medium  CLOSED         NULL          NULL   2019-01-09         2019-01-15       NULL          2019-01-14        NULL
```

Note the above example uses **one** specific `bug_id`; however, the real dataset will have thousands of different bug_ids.

The new dataframe should contain the most current row for each bug along with a few of the important columns from the most current row of the `bug_id`, i.e. severity, status, creation_dttm, etc along with the new `*_dttm` columns.

Comment: why on `verified_dttm`  is date, it should by `NULL`?

Comment: I don't see that verified_dttm is NULL, I realize the columns don't line up pretty :-( but in the final dataframe verified_dttm is 2019-02-14 which is a typo on my part - I'll fix.  It should be 2019-01-14, the first date it entered verified.

Comment: but what is the role that define where or not the date appear?

Comment: Have a look at "groupby" - you can group your dataframe by bug_id and then do something with each group.

Comment: I haven't found a way to make `groupby()` work because I'm not actually aggregating anything, it's more like I'm trying to blend or merge rows.  My current approach has been to use two dataframes, df1 and df2, df1 being the original data with df2 being a subset of df1 based on the maximum `phase_date`, i.e. the row corresponding to the maximum phase_date for each bug_id would be added to df2 (this should be one row per).  From there I need to then figure out how to get the first date where TRUE exists for a given column into df2['new_column_dttm'].

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi If I understand your question correctly, what should happen is if, in df1, `defect_verified_day_flag` is TRUE then the first (min) phase date where it was set to TRUE should be the value set in df2['verified_dttm'].  Someone forwarded me an interesting article about groupby() that I'm going to look at a bit more.  https://www.shanelynn.ie/summarising-aggregation-and-grouping-data-in-python-pandas/

Comment: @Eric `bug_id  creation_dttm   severity    status` are chosen from last line or there is another criterium?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi That is correct, the dttm is populated by the first occurrence but other values should be from the last occurrence.  In my current approach where I'm using two dataframes I have `df2 = df1.sort_values(['bug_id', 'phase_date']).drop_duplicates(subset=['bug_id'], keep='last').drop(columns=[....]).  I'm now at the point where I feel I am ready to try some things; however, I know that there will likely be issues with my two dataframe approach possibly due to indexes, for example, a common error I've seen is SettingWithCopyWarning.

Answer (score 1):

For data like below:

```
   phase_date  bug_id       creation_dttm severity       status  defect_regression_day_flag  defect_reopen_day_flag  defect_backlog_day_flag  defect_resolution_day_flag  defect_rejected_day_flag  defect_verified_day_flag  defect_failedtest_day_flag
0  2019-01-09  113998  2004-01-21 3:15:24   medium          NEW                       False                   False                     True                       False                     False                     False                       False
1  2019-01-10  113998  2004-01-21 3:15:24   medium          NEW                       False                   False                     True                       False                     False                     False                       False
2  2019-01-11  113998  2004-01-21 3:15:24   medium     ASSIGNED                       False                   False                     True                       False                     False                     False                       False
3  2019-01-12  113998  2004-01-21 3:15:24   medium  IN PROGRESS                       False                   False                     True                       False                     False                     False                       False
4  2019-01-13  113998  2004-01-21 3:15:24   medium  IN PROGRESS                       False                   False                     True                       False                     False                     False                       False
5  2019-01-14  113998  2004-01-21 3:15:24   medium     VERIFIED                       False                   False                    False                       False                     False                      True                       False
6  2019-01-15  113998  2004-01-21 3:15:24   medium       CLOSED                       False                   False                     True                        True                     False                     False                       False
7  2019-01-14  113999  2004-01-21 3:15:24   medium     VERIFIED                       False                   False                    False                       False                     False                      True                       False
8  2019-01-15  113999  2004-01-21 3:15:24   medium       CLOSED                       False                   False                     True                        True                     False                     False                       False
```

You need to:

1. group data by `bug_id`
2. for each column in group find first occurrence of `TRUE`
3. collect data and load into new df

```
# group data
grouped_data = df.groupby('bug_id')

# collect data
final_data = []
for name, group in grouped_data:
    last_line = group.iloc[[-1]]
    data = {'bug_id': last_line['bug_id'].values[0], 'creation_dttm': last_line['creation_dttm'].values[0],
            'severity': last_line['severity'].values[0], 'status': last_line['status'].values[0]}

    column_names = list(group.columns)[5:]
    for column in column_names:
        true_occurrence = group[group[column] == True]
        if true_occurrence.shape[0] > 0:
            data[column] = true_occurrence['phase_date'].iloc[0]
        else:
            data[column] = 'NULL'

    final_data.append(data)

# save data
df_final = pd.DataFrame(final_data)
```

**Output:**

```
   bug_id       creation_dttm severity  status defect_regression_day_flag defect_reopen_day_flag defect_backlog_day_flag defect_resolution_day_flag defect_rejected_day_flag defect_verified_day_flag defect_failedtest_day_flag
0  113998  2004-01-21 3:15:24   medium  CLOSED                       NULL                   NULL              2019-01-09                 2019-01-15                     NULL               2019-01-14                       NULL
1  113999  2004-01-21 3:15:24   medium  CLOSED                       NULL                   NULL              2019-01-15                 2019-01-15                     NULL               2019-01-14                       NULL
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try and review this solution today and apply to my dataset for testing.  I do believe though that there may be a typo.  Under "You need to" you have step 1 as groupby [phase_date] however, in your code you have groupby('bug_id').  I do believe bug_id makes more sense, but that also a sort_values may be required here as well.

Comment: @Eric yep i will correct that typo. It you find this solution useful it will by nice when you leave arrow up and accept my answer.

Comment: So I'm actually trying your approach as `grouped_data = df.sort_values['bug_id', 'phase_date']` to ensure that I can be sure I'm grabbing the earliest or latest (as the case may be) record.  And yes, if this helps I will absolutely vote up the answer - Thanks!

Comment: Just noting that sort_values() won't work the same way with the for loop as groupby(), groupby() returns a `<class 'pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy'>` while sort_values() returns a `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`.

Comment: I updated, more from a safety precaution the groupby statement, found that it would work if sorted first. The new statement is `grouped_data = dft.sort_values(['phase_date']).groupby('bug_id') ` Everything appears to be working, I'm going to vote this solution up.  Though I do wonder if there is a way to instead create a function and the use groupby()'s `aggfunc` option.  Perhaps something for me to look at after some more testing.

Comment: @Eric yep you can try do this with groupby & agg some function